# Add ~/projects/*/bin directory in environment PATH (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, environment-variables, path

Everything is in the title. I know how to add new path in the environment `PATH` variable but I would like to make it recursive by automatically adding `/bin` folders of all my future projects.

Something like, replacing this:

```
PATH=$PATH:~/projects/project1/bin
PATH=$PATH:~/projects/project2/bin
..
PATH=$PATH:~/projects/projectN/bin
```

By this:

```
PATH=$PATH:~/projects/*/bin
```

Problem: each time I put the `*` in it, this is not recognized by the system. Do you see a way to do that ?

I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish something like this you'll need to put some code in what's called a subcommand in most shells. In Bash its notation is `$(...some command...)`.

#### Approach

```
$ find ~ -iregex ".*project.*/bin" | xargs | sed 's/ /:/g'
```

This one liner will produce a list of directories that contain a `/bin` sub-directory within them. It isn't 100% perfect, since it cannot handle directories which contain spaces in their names, but if you know your situation conforms to this rule then you can use it.

Using the above snippet you'd construct your `$PATH` like so:

```
PATH=$PATH:$(find ~ -iregex ".*project.*/bin" | xargs | sed 's/ /:/g')
```

#### Example

For this example I'm going to use `$MYPATH` as a stand-in for `$PATH`. To start we have some directories already contained in `$MYPATH`.

```
$ MYPATH=/path1/bin:/path2/bin
$ echo $MYPATH
/path1/bin:/path2/bin
```

Now to add all `~/project*/bin` directories to `$MYPATH`:

```
$ MYPATH=$MYPATH:$(find ~ -iregex ".*project.*/bin" | xargs | sed 's/ /:/g')
$ echo $MYPATH
/path1/bin:/path2/bin:/Users/slm/project1/bin:/Users/slm/project2/bin:/Users/slm/project3/bin
```